# Garbage value using memcpy() in c

Tags: c

I'm using memcpy() to copy a struct to another struct

```
struct question{
    char * ques;
    ...
}

void copy(struct question *c1, struct question *q1){
    c1 = (struct question *)malloc(sizeof(struct question));
    c1->ques= (char *)malloc(sizeof(&(q1->ques))); 
    memcpy(c1,q1,sizeof(&(q1)));
}
```

After run the copy function, I tried to print out the name of c1 but there are some garbage char in it. (for example, the ques is "helloWord2020", the result would be helloword[###],# means some garbage character ).

q1 is on the stack and c1 is NULL before the copy() is called.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but in C you [shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`](max(Node *root)).

Comment: As for ***one*** of your problems: `q1->ques` is of type `char *` and `&q1->ques` is of type `char **`. The `sizeof` of *any* pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to (which means that even `sizeof q1->ques` would be wrong).

Comment: Also remember that argument in C are passed *by value*, meaning the value is *copied* into the argument variable. Modifying the argument variable (like assigning to it) will only modify the local copy, not the original that was used in the function call. And what do you think happens with `c1->name` when you copy `q1` over the whole `c1` structure?

Comment: Your function just allocates space , writes to it, and then leaks memory. After `copy` returns, `c1` no longer exists

Comment: @ Some programmer dude So what should be the size? Before I change to " sizeof q1->name" it was "sizeof char" but I think it was wrong.  Oh sorry, that should be c1->ques.

Comment: @ M.M I don't really understand why `c1` no longer exits after copy()? I think I allocate memory for c1 and it won't disappear until I free it.

Comment: For a null-terminated string you need to use `strlen` to get its length. Don't forget the nul-terminator.

Comment: When the function returns, the local variable `c1` no longer exists, any memory it might point to is lost. As well as `c1->name` which you loose already with the `memcpy` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems, if your intention is to copy an instance of a question with a new allocation, you can't do that with a pointer, `c1` as an in-parameter.

Further, you need to allocate enough memory to do a string copy.  And use strcpy to copy the contents.

Instead of this:

```
c1 = (struct question *)malloc(sizeof(struct question));
c1->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(&(q1->ques))); 
memcpy(c1,q1,sizeof(&(q1)));
```

this:

```
struct question* copy(struct question *q1) {

     struct question* c1 = NULL;

     if (q1 != NULL) {

         size_t question_size = sizeof(struct question);
         size_t string_size = q1->ques ? (strlen(q1->ques)+1) : 0;

         c1 = malloc(question_size);

         if (string_size > 0) {
             c1->ques = string_size ? malloc(string_size) : NULL;
             strcpy(c1 ->ques, q1->ques);
         }
         else {
             c1->ques = NULL;
         }
     }

     return c1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, but I still don't get why I can't use memcpy to copy string. And can I use memcpy to copy int/float/size_t ... and array?

Comment: You can certainly use `memcpy(c1->ques, q1->ques, string_size)`.  But it's non-standard for a string copy operation and reduces readability.

Answer (score 1):

In C parameters are passed by value rather than by reference. Thus, if you want to call a function and pass it a pointer which it can change you need to pass a *pointer to the pointer*. In addition, I'm assuming that the `ques` element of the structure is a pointer to a string and as such, I suspect that rather than just copying the pointer you want to allocate enough memory to hold the text and the copy the question text. Thus we get:

```
void copy(struct question **c1, struct question *q1)
  {
  *c1 = malloc(sizeof(struct question));
  memcpy(*c1, q1, sizeof(struct question));
  /* or **c1 = *q1, if you prefer */

  (*c1)->ques = malloc(strlen(q1->ques)+1); 
  strcpy((*c1)->ques, q1->ques);
  }
```

Also, given that this is C, you shouldn't be casting the return value from `malloc`.

Comment: It's also possible to write `**c1 = *q1;` instead of `memcpy`